# PHP SDK + Code Igniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

First, I downloaded the Facebook PHP SDK and applied the first answer in here:
[Using Facebook PHP-SDK 3.x to register/login user with Codeigniter 2.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454238/using-facebook-php-sdk-3-x-to-register-login-user-with-codeigniter-2-1-0)

In my controller:

1. I try to get the user: $this->facebook->getUser(); .. If it's 0, I call another function $this->facebook_login(); - else I save some data in the database like name for example.
2. In facebook_login(), a Login Url is generated: $this->facebook->getLoginUrl() - and is passed to the view, which displays it.
3. So far I click on the login url and it redirects to Facebook, asks for approval and authentication and so on - then redirects me back to the page in "1".
4. The problem is, getUser is returning zero. I printed the $*SESSION variable and found out that only fb*{appId}_state is being set.

I tried creating another php file (login.php) that is not in the CI folder with the following code:

```
<?php

define('BASEPATH', '');
require_once('application/libraries/facebook.php');

$fb = new Facebook(array('appId'=>'...', 'secret'=>'...'));

$user = $fb->getUser();

if($user == 0){
    $login = $fb->getLoginUrl();
    echo '<a href="'.$login.'">Login</a>';
} else {
    print_r($fb->api('/me'));
}

?>
```

If I visit login.php then visit the page in "1" above - getUser returns the user id and $_SESSION contains the user details.Therefore, I guess the problem is with CodeIgniter but I am not sure how to solve it.

I searched and tried several solutions but that's the best I could do. If possible, I don't want to use the JS SDK.

Thank you

Comment: In the constructor found in the link at the beginning of the question, add this before loading the facebook library: parse_str( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_REQUEST );

Comment: Is the `cookie_domain` variable set properly to your domain in application/config/config.php?

Comment: Yes. I figured out the solution and posted it as a comment. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and wrote a blog post about it [here](http://www.galalaly.me/index.php/2012/04/using-facebook-php-sdk-3-with-codeigniter-2-1/).

Comment: @GalalAly Please do not link to an external site, as there is no guarantee that site will exist in the future. Instead, post your solution here.