# facebook sdk 3 login codeigniter - An error occurred

Tags: codeigniter, sdk, facebook-login

I'm using codeigniter 2.1.2 and facebook api php sdk 3.1.1 (last versions)
I used the way at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454238/using-facebook-php-sdk-3-x-to-register-login-user-with-codeigniter-2-1-0?answertab=votes#tab-top)

that exist at the answer. but when I try to login its worked for me only (when I'm using my facebook account). otherwise when anyone try to log in this message appear:

‏**An error occurred with logging in to site. Please try again later.‏**

this is the link at my website: 
http://www.tahainshad.com/login4

these are my app settings..

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to get your application approved from Facebook for it to be visible publicly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `tahainshad.com` to the **app domains** field. Giving the top level domain is enough, facebook will accept redirects to any subdomain of that (like www.).

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the process is working successfully.
I've another question please, how do I make a request registration information pop-up window, instead of redirecting to a page on Facebook?

Comment: It's done with the [Facebook Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), once you got that setup, use the [FB.login()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) method. Please see the [client side authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/) page of the documentation.