# How to implement codeigniter signup with facebook signup

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I am required to implement the functionality of registering a user onto my current website using the Facebook signup process

Can anyone provide me with a link to some guide or blog where some help regarding this has been provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your imagination. Simply look at the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/). It's not as good documented as it could be, but it works it you read everything at least twice.

Make an authentication, retrieve the information you want such as [email](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) etc if needed. If the information you get from Facebook is enough, create a account like any other, but save the Facebook ID so you can log them in next time.

If you need more information, you can retrieve the [Facebook data](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) once the other data have been submited and register the user.

If making your own version is too hard or time consuming, google for an existing one. Tags: **codeigniter facebook login**

---

Personally, I use [Facebook's graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) through a personally made library which handles all of my calls to Facebook. With a simple and clean API such as the one they provide, it gets easy enough to manage without a php sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official article from the Facebook developer portal on registering users using the Facebook registration plugin

< http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/ >

Also, here's a plugin I just found on GitHub. I think it's exactly what you are looking for

< https://github.com/falexandrou/Codeigniter-Social-Register >

EDIT:

Also, please see this SO Question: [Using Facebook PHP-SDK 3.x to register/login user with Codeigniter 2.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454238/using-facebook-php-sdk-3-x-to-register-login-user-with-codeigniter-2-1-0)

Comment: thanks man... i just downlaoded this... the github link that you just posted... will it work fine?

Comment: can i use this in my codeignter version i.e facebook registration plugin given here     http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

Comment: I have not used this but I guess it will work. Author says you need to do some work on your end before it will work.

Comment: ohkkk...... i will try to implement this after taking an brief overview from all other sources

Comment: hi.... sign up with facebook worked but there are problems in sign-up with twitter....... can anyone please help....

Comment: You should ask another question on the new problem.. Clearly describe your problem, result, expected result and some sample code.